# Replace double new line character with only one?

Tags: javascript, replace, newline

How could I remove every double new line character with only one?

```
var string = "this is a ↵↵↵↵ test there will ↵↵ be more ↵↵↵↵ newline characters"
```

something like this

```
var string = "this is a ↵↵ test there will ↵ be more ↵↵ newline characters"
```

I've already tried this, but this replaces all new lines, i want to keep the single ones

```
string.replace(/[\n\n]/g, '')
```

Comment: Remove the `[...]`

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by this [...]?

Edit: I get it you mean the brackets in the regex, I'm trying it out! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

`[\n\n]` character class works as `Logical OR`. `[\n\n]` this means match `\n` or `\n`. what you need is `\n` followed by `\n`. So just remove the `[]` character class.

```js
let str = `this is a 



test there will 

be more 



newline characters`

console.log(str.replace(/\n\n/g, '\n'))
console.log(str.replace(/\n+/g, '\n')) // <--- simply you can do this
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string = string.replace(/\n{2}/g, '\n');

console.log(string);
```

That will do what you explained... but I believe you need this...

```
string = string.replace(/\n+/g, '\n');

console.log(string);
```